# Why do not add css style in my react project?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I do make a style in my react project. Like as

style.css:

```
.headingStyle {
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;

}
```

and my react component is:

```
import React from 'react'
import  '../cse_component/style.css'


export default function heardTitle() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 ClassName='headingStyle'>Todo List</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But why I can not change anything in my project?

Comment: 1) `className` not `ClassName`. 2) Your component name needs to be in PascalCase: `HeardTitle` not `heardTitle`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misstype the `className` prop. It should be `className` not `ClassName` using capital C.

Try changing it from this

```js
<h1 ClassName='headingStyle'>Todo List</h1>
```

into this:

```js
<h1 className='headingStyle'>Todo List</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a typo error on `ClassName` use `className`.

```
import React from 'react'
import  '../cse_component/style.css'


export default function heardTitle() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='headingStyle'>Todo List</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

For inline css use the code as `<h1 style={{ background-color: purple;text-align: center; }} >Todo List</h1>`